# How can I sanitize / serialize input data with @nestjs/graphql

Tags: graphql, nestjs, class-transformer

I'm working on a NestJs app with graphql, and I'm trying to sanitize my resolvers inputs with class-transformer like this :

```
@InputType()
export class CreateUserInput {
  @Field(() => String)
  @Transform(({ value }) => value.trim())
  email!: string;
}
```

But the Transform content is never executed.

How can I sanitize properly with decorator in an InputType ?

Comment: Do you have the `ValidationPipe` used and the `transform: true` option set?

Comment: Thank you it works! Can you write an answer so I can validate it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use the `@Transform()` decorator, you need to have the [`ValidationPipe`](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation) bound to the route, resolver, or server, and you need to set the `transform` option to `true`

Comment: how can i use the @Exclude decorator?